# How do I add more information to Wordpress Registration page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, registration

I am wanting to add a small amount of text to the websites registration page, but as simple as this may sound I am having trouble. The website uses BuddyPress & runs on the Storefront Theme.

The image shows where I am wanting to add the text. I would imagine this could be done from inside my functions.php but unsure how to do this. Any advice?

[image: Image where the text needs to be displayed]

Comment: are you using default wordpress registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would imagine this could be done from inside my functions.php but
>   unsure how to do this.

Yes, that's correct.

And here's a code snippet that will add the custom message as you highlighted in the screen capture you provided.

*(the HTML code is just an example; feel free to edit the `class`, wrap the `P` in a `DIV`, etc.)*

```
// Add custom HTML before the "Complete Sign Up" button in the "Profile Details"
// column on the BuddyPress registration page.
add_action( 'bp_signup_profile_fields', function() {
    // Start editing below.
    ?>
        <p class="notice-check-inbox">
            Please remember to check your emails and confirm registration for a
            <strong>10% discount voucher</strong>!
        </p>
    <?php
    // End editing.
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Sally! - Works perfectly!  =)